# Not being able to Login to Moodle using OpenLDAP User

Tags: linux, apache, authentication, ldap, centos6

I am new to configuration of LDAP and Moodle. I installed the OpenLDAP 2.4.40 on Linux Centos 6 and configured it successfully using this link. Then I got to another Link which provides the configuration of LDAP Server Authentication on Moodle 3.2.

After implementing all the configuration, the login to the Moodle using a LDAP user is not working knowing that all the configurations are applied as documented in the above links.

I installed the Apache Directory Studio and configure the connection to the LDAP Server successfully. Hereafter is a snapshot of the LDAP Server Tree:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLhMb.png]

Then I got to the LDAP server installed in Linux thru using putty tool and run the "ldapsearch -x -LLL -b dc=sorce,dc=online" and it works fine.

My Moodle Authentication configuration parameters of LDAP Server are as follows:

- Distinguished Name - bind user is set to the Root User:
  **cn=Manager,dc=sorce,dc=online User**
- Type: **posixAccount (rfc2307)**
- Context is set to the "users" entry:  **ou=Users,dc=sorce,dc=online**
- All the passwords are double checked

However, after implementing all the above configurations, I`m still not able to connect to Moodle using LDAP Users, and I got the following error:

**LDAP-module cannot connect to any servers: Server: '80.79.155.44', Connection: 'Resource id #82', Bind result: ''**

My Moodle installation is hosted in a cloud account,  the LDAP Server is installed in a local office server (Linux Centos 6), and the Apache Directory Studio is installed in my PC (Windows 7)

Any ideas regarding how I can make Moodle authenticate LDAP Users and login..please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the SSO part of Moodle to work, you need to config NTLM on your server as well as LDAP.  Once you've added the server as a domain member (so it can pass-through / impersonate authentication requests to you DC[s]). See: https://docs.moodle.org/24/en/NTLM_authentication

Once you get it to the point that winbind ("wbinfo -u" from bash) can successfully 'speak' to your domain ad fetch a list of users, your basically there.

This is an old question and you've surely moved on since then, but having recently gone through this and happening upon this article, thought I'd post this hint for anyone else encountering similar challenges.